# How to use live feature of live server

Tags: server

Even though I have gone through the questions similar being asked, I am not clear as to what is Live Server and how to use it. Based on few documentation I tried to install Live Server and I feel that it is same as Server Installation. So what is the difference and how to use true Live Server.

Please guide me.

Manish Chawda

Comment: You don't install a *live* system, you just *boot* and use it.   On shutdown, nothing is changed on the computer you used, unless you opted to install it during the *live* session.

Comment: FYI:  You can use a *live* system and save data to network drives, even local drives.. but by default a *live* system runs in memory only, so all changes/saves by default are lost on reboot, unless you navigate & purposely save them to media that isn't in RAM   (also desktop or server; it's still a *live* system; Ubuntu Server historically wasn't available on *live* media requiring installation before you could *try* or use it

Answer (score 1):

You don't install a *live* system, you just *boot* and use it.   On shutdown, nothing is changed on the computer you used, unless you opted to install it during the *live* session.

You can use a *live* system and save data to network drives, even local drives.. but by default a *live* system runs in memory only, so all changes/saves by default are lost on reboot, unless you navigate & purposely save them to media that isn't in RAM

Also desktop or server; it's still a *live* system

Ubuntu Server historically wasn't available on *live* media requiring installation before you could *try* or use it, it's not available using the great *live* media that allows you to *fix* problems using it :)

Comment: these are mostly just comments & thoughts collected..  (without edit; to me the topic is duplicate & already covered... server isn't really any different)